# Is there a way to dynamically update a synonym file without restarting Solr server?

Tags: search, solr, solrj, synonym

As we know there is a **synonym.txt** file in conf directory, which I wanted to update whenever I found some new synonym words...

So is there any way to update that file dynamically without restarting the **Solr server** and will my search result consider the new synonym words??

please help me if anyone have any idea..
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can build your own [SynonymFilterFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-ALPHA/org/apache/solr/analysis/SynonymFilterFactory.html) that extends the original and use your a custom [FSTSynonymFilterFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-core/3.4.0/org/apache/solr/analysis/FSTSynonymFilterFactory.java) as delegator.
your SynonymFilterFactory should extends the original SlowSynonymFilterFactory and call:

```
map = loadSolrSynonyms(loader, true, analyzer);
```

whenever you want to reload the synonym file.

For reloading your file when it changes you can use a watchdog thread that awke up every X time and check whether the sysnonim file was changed or you can use some [file watcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) to get notification when the file was changed.

Comment: Shem: thanks for ur reply...
Can u please give me example how to write custom factoy and how to use it in scheme.xml?
Give me some link to refer...if u have.

I am new to Solr I dont have good idea.

Comment: can you help me with : Programatically reload the solr-core server / restart the server.
I am using solrj.

Comment: That's mean that after you created your jar with your filter you should replace the solr jar in the web app lib and restart the solr service

Answer (score 4):

Solr provides [Managed Synonym Graph Filter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/filter-descriptions.html#managed-synonym-graph-filter) to manage synonyms using a REST API (in this example via `/solr/collection_name/schema/analysis/synonyms/english` endpoint):

```xml
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymGraphFilterFactory" managed="english"/>
    <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/> <!-- required on index analyzers after graph filters -->
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymGraphFilterFactory" managed="english"/>
</analyzer>
```

A core reload is needed to apply synonyms changes. Solr provides a REST API for this too [CoreAdmin API Reload](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/coreadmin-api.html#coreadmin-reload) `admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=core-name`

> The RELOAD action loads a new core from the configuration of an existing, registered Solr core. While the new core is initializing, the existing one will continue to handle requests. When the new Solr core is ready, it takes over and the old core is unloaded.

Comment: Just to clarify: this feature is available starting from Solr 7.0.0.