# How to reload the Solr core using SolrJ?

Tags: apache, search, solr, solrj, synonym

I am using SolrJ for indexing my data. I am updating the Synonym.txt file dynamically but Solr server is not getting the latest changes from Synonym.txt file, my previous question is [how to update synonym.txt file dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555696/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-update-a-synonym-file-without-restarting-solr-serv/11555992#11555992)
So I have to reload/restart the Solr core programatically...
so how can I do that...?

thanks in advance...

Comment: thanks @javanna : and yes...I always forgot to do that :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code should be what you're looking for:

```
CoreAdminRequest adminRequest = new CoreAdminRequest();
adminRequest.setAction(CoreAdminAction.RELOAD);
CoreAdminResponse adminResponse = adminRequest.process(new HttpSolrServer(solrUrl));
NamedList<NamedList<Object>> coreStatus = adminResponse.getCoreStatus();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @javanna...can you please tell me what adminResponse.getCoreStatus(); returns?
I am getting coreStatus as 'null' ...

Comment: It should return the content of the status element within the response...are you sure the solrUrl is correct?

Comment: yes,I am doing indexing and searching using the SolrServer using same url,which is working fine...

Comment: I see, but if you are working with a multicore Solr you are indexing on a specific core, while the coreadmin is not within each core. The url you have to provide is without the core name.

Comment: Ok, the url is correct. Have you enabled the [core admin interface](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin)? Can you reach it from your browser? http://localhost:8983/solr/cores?action=RELOAD&core=corename

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14209/discussion-between-milind-ensarm-and-javanna)

Answer (score 1):

SolrJ contains a static convenience method for that in `CoreAdminRequest` class:

```java
reloadCore("<YOUR_CORE_NAME>", solrClient)
```